# can't get phantomjs 1.9 to render Leaflet SVG vector layers to png

Tags: phantomjs, leaflet

I'm building a mapping application using the Leaflet API http://leafletjs.com/.

I would like to use phantomjs to generate static screenshots of maps.

As an example, attempting to render this page:

http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson-example.html

using

phantomjs examples/rasterize.js http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson-example.html test.png

results in an image that's missing the SVG overlay. I have tried this using the prebuilt binaries under Windows 7 and Fedora Core 15. In addition, I compiled it from source under Fedora Core 15. All builds on both platforms yielded the same behavior.

Has anyone had success rendering Leaflet maps to PNG using phantomjs?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried incrementing the timeout in the [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) script on line 29 from 200 to something a bit higher?

Comment: Yea, I thought about timeout issues as well In one test, I actually modified rasterize.js to include the waitFor example and caused it to wait for a flag that I would only set after all vector shapes had been drawn. I verified it with console.log messages. All no no avail. (Good thinking though.)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue and increasing the timeout (at least to 5000) didn't make SVG overlays appear in the PDF.

It's probably this issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11171

Switching to Leaflet master branch fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Excellent. I will give that a try. (I searched through the whole bug list but missed that one. Thank you for the pointer!)

Comment: Using the master branch, as of today, does not solve the problem. Interestingly, in my test cases here, the stable release at least renders Marker layers (but not polylines) but the master branch causes phantomjs to not even render the markers. It does demonstrate, however, that the version of Leaflet used has an effect on phantomjs.

Comment: I don't have markers in my map, but here's what I have working, with Leaflet master and PhantomJS 1.9 built from source: 3 group layers containing polygons, some with transparent fills and some without, over a raster tile layer.

Comment: Leaflet master from how long ago?

Comment: After more investigation it seems that it's somehow related to zoomAnimation. If I set the zoomAnimation, markerZoomAnimation option to false, suddenly maps render. It may be related to the MarkerCluster plugin. Not sure yet.